# Report Definition Local Definition Error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, reporting-services

i have a very strange problem. 
i'm designing a winform app using C# and SQL. i have one reportviewer(its a local report) that is bound to a dataset that holds data of a select query.
the report viewer is working ok in both release and debug modes, i'm able to view data, able to export it without any hindrances..

So i went ahead and published my app using Install shield, along with all my other forms. and made the setup file

i installed the setup file on my PC for testing purpose. All forms are working fine except the report viewer. when i click on my generate report button, the error "An error Occurred during Local Report Processing, the report Defination for Report2.rdlc was not specified. Could not find.
C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\C0AR0PT5.VRJ\DBE8ENNT.GWW\s.i...tion_61336ddcb5db67e9_0001.0005_09635aa1235e262b\Report2.rdlc "

What could be the reason, its working in VS2012 in both Debug as well as release mode.

Please help, What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should embed the report as a project resource. As it seems, your application expects the report's RDLC file to be present outside the application as a file on the disk.

---

On your comment "How do I do that?":

Set "Build Type" for the RDLC file in Visual Studio to "Embedded Resource" and then [read this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14258a27-0137-425f-b5e8-6747ca476359/load-rdlc-as-embedded-resource-into-the-viewer?forum=vsreportcontrols). I'd like to add that you need to add the full namespace.

Example: your RDLC file is "MyReport.rdlc" and it's in the sub-folder "reports" of a project with default namespace "com.example.MyFirstProject". Then you need to set `ReportEmbeddedResource` to

```
com.example.MyFirstProject.resports.MyReport.rdlc
```